# Fastest way of drawing lots of circles in SkiaSharp

Tags: skiasharp

I'm using SkiaSharp in WPF to draw some custom charts that show lots of points in a scatter plot like in the image below :

[image]

I'm currently doing this with the `canvas.DrawCircle` method, but performance isn't great for the number of points we have (upwards of 50k, and anything up to around 200k).

Is there a more performant way of doing this? `canvas.DrawPoint` and `canvas.DrawRect` are a little more performant, but ideally I want to be able to render a circle.

The array of points is static, however the user can zoom/pan, so static data, but live view (zoom/pan) onto that data, if that makes sense.